# VSTO Powerpoint AddIn - how to Add Picture to sliede

Tags: c#, vsto, office-interop

ive tried to add a picture by clicking a button the TaskPanel in VSTO PP AddIn, the code works in WinForms.

Now i try to implement this with a Xaml hostet TaskPanel, but it wont work(same code).

It do not compile, but no error is shown:

```
public void AddImageToSlideEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Cast sender as button for tag attribute
        Button button = sender as Button;

        Powerpoint.Application presentation = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application;



        //save current slide in "currentSlide"
        var currentSlide = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWindow.View.Slide;

        //TODO: Add Picture does not work
        Powerpoint.Shape shape = currentSlide.Shapes.AddPicture(button.Tag, true, true, 250, 250);
    }
```

who can help out here?

thx a lot

Answer (score 0):

You need to check out the parameters you pass to the [Shapes.AddPicture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.shapes.addpicture) function. Most probably the button doesn't have the `Tag` property set and etc.

The following sample shows that you need to pass the path and file name of the picture.

```
myDocument.Shapes.AddPicture FileName:="c:\microsoft office\" & _ 
    "clipart\music.bmp", LinkToFile:=msoTrue, SaveWithDocument:=msoTrue, _ 
    Left:=100, Top:=100, Width:=70, Height:=70
```

Answer (score 0):

Ive checked all today - no result.

so i started a new test AddIn - the old code works :) but i dont know what was the problem.

But thanks for youre help!